# Generating Missing Spec Files for RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, specifications

Is there any command available for generating all missing spec files for existing models / controllers? I have a project that has several models that have been generated with out spec files.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could just run the generator and ignore the models/migrations/fixtures.

```
ruby script/generate rspec_model User --skip-migration --skip-fixture --skip
```

I've been looking into writing something to do this but there hasn't been any interest from others.

Answer (score 17):

In rspec-rails-2 which is intended for Rails 3 all of the rspec generators have been removed.

You can solve this problem by running the rails model generator. You can add -s to skip any existing files and --migration=false to skip creating the migration file.

Like so:

```
rails generate model example -s --migration=false
```

Comment: Worked for me! rails 3.2.13

Answer (score 1):

If the number of missing specs is rather small, you could simply run the `rails generate` commands for each components with missing specs.

When a conflict arises, simply opt not to overwrite the original file. The generator will ignore the existing files and generate the missing ones.

Answer (score 0):

https://gist.github.com/omenking/7774140

```
require 'fileutils'
namespace :spec do

  def progress name, x, y
    print "\r #{name}: #{x}/#{y} %6.2f%%" % [x.to_f/y * 100]
  end

  def generate_files name
    kind       = name.to_s.singularize
    collection = Dir.glob Rails.root.join('app',name.to_s,'**','*').to_s
    root       = Rails.root.join('app',name.to_s).to_s<<'/'
    ext        = case name
                   when :controllers then  '_controller.rb'
                   when :models      then  '.rb'
                end
    count = collection.count
    collection.each_with_index do |i,index| 
      `rails g #{kind} #{$1} -s` if i =~ /#{root}(.+)#{ext}/
      progress name, index, count
    end
  end

  task generate_missing: :environment do
    generate_files :controllers
    generate_files :models
  end
end

# if you dont want certian things generated than
# configure your generators in your application.rb eg.
#
#   config.generators do |g|
#     g.orm :active_record
#     g.template_engine :haml
#     g.stylesheets false
#     g.javascripts false
#     g.test_framework :rspec,
#                      fixture: false,
#                      fixture_replacement: nil
#   end
#
```